# Bigcommerce PHP API - No data returned

Tags: php, api, curl, bigcommerce

I'm using the single file PHP library. I've got the store connecting, but I am getting no data back. Here is my script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', True);
 require 'bigcommerce.php';
    use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

    $settings = array('store_url' => 'https://STORE_URL_REDACTED.mybigcommerce.com','username' => 'USERNAME_REDACTED', 'api_key' => 'API_KEY_REDACTED');

    if( 
        (array_key_exists('store_url', (array)$settings)) &&
        (array_key_exists('username', $settings)) && 
        (array_key_exists('api_key', $settings)) 
    ) {
        // Config Basic
        Bigcommerce::configure(
            array(
                'store_url' => $settings['store_url'],
                'username'  => $settings['username'],
                'api_key'   => $settings['api_key']
            )
        );
        Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
        Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);
    }    

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

$orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders();

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;
}
?>
```

I've got output writing on the curl commands in bigcommerce.php, and I can see that I am actually connecting to the store:

- About to connect() to STORE_ID_REDACTED.mybigcommerce.com port 443 (#0) * Trying REDACTED... * connected * Connected to STORE_ID_REDACTED.mybigcommerce.com (REDACTED) port 443 (#0) * successfully set certificate verify locations: * CAfile: cacert.pem CApath: /etc/ssl/certs * SSL connection using RC4-SHA * Server certificate: * subject: C=US; postalCode=49519; ST=Michigan; L=Wyoming; street=3343 Perry Ave SW; O=REDACTED; OU=InstantSSL; CN=REDACTED * start date: 2011-08-22 00:00:00 GMT * expire date: 2016-08-21 23:59:59 GMT * issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO High-Assurance Secure Server CA * SSL certificate verify ok. * Server auth using Basic with user 'USERNAME_REDACTED' > GET /api/v2/products HTTP/1.1 Authorization: Basic REDACTED Host: store-STORE_ID_REDACTED.mybigcommerce.com Accept: application/json < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Tue, 03 Dec 2013 16:32:57 GMT < Server: Apache < Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Dec 2013 06:25:44 +0000 < X-BC-ApiLimit-Remaining: 17167 < X-BC-Store-Version: 7.6.0 < X-Powered-By: PleskLin < Transfer-Encoding: chunked < Content-Type: application/json < * Connection #0 to host STORE_ID_REDACTED.mybigcommerce.com left intact * Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host STORE_ID_REDACTED.mybigcommerce.com * Connected to STORE_ID_REDACTED.mybigcommerce.com (REDACTED) port 443 (#0) * Server auth using Basic with user 'USERNAME_REDACTED' > GET /api/v2/orders HTTP/1.1 Authorization: Basic REDACTED Host: REDACTED Accept: application/json < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Tue, 03 Dec 2013 16:32:58 GMT < Server: Apache < Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Nov 2010 17:40:55 +0000 < X-BC-ApiLimit-Remaining: 17162 < X-BC-Store-Version: 7.6.0 < X-Powered-By: PleskLin < Transfer-Encoding: chunked < Content-Type: application/json < * Connection #0 to host STORE_ID_REDACTED.mybigcommerce.com left intact * Closing connection #0

I get the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/zetaphor/public_html/bigcommerce-api-php-master/coupons.php
```

My returned arrays contain no data.

I am running a LAMP stack using PHP 5.3.3, cURL enabled

Comment: try doing a var_dump of $products

Comment: @Satya - var_dump returns NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing that problem in php class, so i have done this using CURL,
You can get your stores products, orders  and  coupon.

here is the code.

```
    $username = 'your username'; 
    $password = 'your key';
    $url = ' your store url';
    $product_url = $url.'/api/v2/products.json';

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    //returning retrieved feed

    $product_rec  = json_decode($curlData);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($product_rec);
```

now for orders use

```
    $order_url =  $url.'/api/v2/orders.json';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is normally another line below the setCipher line to "verify peer". Try adding that in so that it would look like:

```
Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);
```

Edit: to be clear, I think this is a key piece for the server to check that your certificate is valid.

Comment: I've added this line, with no change.